# Difference between "collections" package and "_collections" (with underscore)

Tags: python

What is the difference between the two python packages `collections` and `_collections`? I guess that `_collections` is probably a private implementation of `collections`. But I was looking for a more extensive and accurate explanation. I have seen both being used in codes, e.g.

```
from _collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(int)
dd['a'] += 1
print(dd)
```

`[out]: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 1})`

```
from _collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(int)
dd['a'] += 1
print(dd)
```

`[out]: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 1}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`collections` is the [Python package](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/v3.6.1/Lib/collections), `_collections` the [C extension module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c). The former wraps the latter.

You generally want to import from `collections`; the `_collections` module is an implementation detail.